# Sunspot in rails 4.How to search character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, gemfile

My project is about an online Mobile shopping site.

I'm trying to search in Full-text-search by Solr. When I search "Lumia",it show all Phones have name is Lumia. But now I search "Lu",it doesnt show anything.

What should I do to when I search "L" or "Lu" or "mia",it still show all Phones Lumia ?

I search for the field :name of model Phone.

My code:

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
searchable do
   text :name
end

class SearchController < ApplicationController  
def create
   @a = Phone.search do
      fulltext get
   end
   @result = @a.results
   render :index
end

private
   def get
       params[:keyword]
   end
```

The form search:

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path do  %>
    <%= text_field_tag :keyword,params[:keyword] %>
    <%= submit_tag :Search %>
<%end%>
```